# Mongoose Node - findOne Query not working

Tags: node.js, mongoose, model

Mongoose model.findOne() not working. Below are the snipped of the code which I am using:

```
console.log('No');
global.LoginList.findOne({"role": "admin", username: req.body.username.toLowerCase()}, function (error, data) {
    console.log('Yes');
});
```

I can see on node terminal as 'No' but I can't see 'Yes' in the execution. Database connection also shows success result.
What might be a reason for this behaviour. Please help.

Comment: If you put a log after `findOne` does that get output? Sounds like the code fails when attempting to run e.g. does `body.username` _definitely_ exist?

Comment: I tried to execute like also 'global.LoginList.findOne({}, function(error, data) { })' . But not working here too.

Comment: How are you setting up `LoginList`? `global.x` seems suspect to me, why are you relying on the global Node env to reference your model?

Comment: I declared global variable like this: **global.LoginList = require('../Models/login');**. Same was working previously.